# undefined reference issue when including header

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

I build a project in C that suppose to create an "assembly" compiled file.
I have these files :

**main.c** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "FirstTransition.h"
#include "Constants.h"
int main() {
   return firstTransition(TEMP_FILE); 
}
```

**FirstTransition.h**

```
#ifndef FIRSTTRANSITIONH
#define FIRSTTRANSITIONH
int firstTransition(char*);
#endif
```

**FirstTransition.c**

```
/*This file contain the first transition method.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Constants.h"
#include "Structs.h"
#include "UtilsFuncs.h"
int firstTransition (char *fileName)
{
    int IC=100,DC=0; /*IC - Instructions counter, DC - Data counter.*/
    FILE *insFile; /*Instructions file pointer.*/ 
    instNode *listOfInstructions;
    instNode *temp;
    if((insFile=fopen(fileName,"r"))==NULL)
    {
        perror("cannot open file!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    listOfInstructions = buildInstructionsList(insFile);
    temp = listOfInstructions;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s->",temp->words);
    }
    
    if (fclose(insFile))
    {
        perror("cannot close file!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**UtilsFuncs.h**

```
#ifndef UTILSFUNCSH
#define UTILSFUNCSH


#include <stdio.h>
#include "Structs.h"
instNode* buildInstructionsList(FILE *);

#endif
```

**UtilsFuncs.c**

```
/*
This file contains all the utilites functions for the project.
*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Structs.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "UtilsFuncs.h"

instNode* buildInstructionsList(FILE *insFile)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN] ={0};/*varible for reading the lines.*/
    instNode *head = NULL;
    instNode *pos = NULL;
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, insFile))
    {
        if(pos == NULL) /*first insertion*/
        {
            head = (instNode*)malloc(sizeof(instNode));
            pos = head;
            head->words = line;
            head->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            pos->next = (instNode*)malloc(sizeof(instNode));
            pos->next->words=line;
            pos->next->next=NULL;
            pos=pos->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

and I have also this **makefile**:

```
myprog:main.o firstTransition.o 
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.o firstTransition.o -o myprog 
main.o: main.c FirstTransition.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.c -o main.o
firstTransition.o: FirstTransition.c Constants.h FirstTransition.h UtilsFuncs.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic FirstTransition.c -o firstTransition.o
UtilsFuncs.o: UtilsFuncs.c Constants.h Structs.h UtilsFuncs.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic UtilsFuncs.c -o UtilsFuncs.o
```

I have this error when I try to perform "make" in the terminal:

> gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.o firstTransition.o -o myprog
> /usr/bin/ld: firstTransition.o: in function `firstTransition': FirstTransition.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to` buildInstructionsList' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [makefile:2: myprog] Error 1

What is the issue? why I cannot in run this code?
It is not creating object file to UtilsFuncs...
I tried to remove the header guard but it didn't help as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't link `UtilsFuncs.o` to your main program

Comment: it doesnt even been created...

Comment: Because it is not listed in dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add UtilsFuncs.o before FirstTransition.o when you link your program:

```
 gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.o UtilsFuncs.o firstTransition.o -o myprog
```